# Pollyjs rest persister doesn't catch any request with cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, pollyjs

I use [pollyjs](https://github.com/Netflix/pollyjs) with the [persister-rest](https://netflix.github.io/pollyjs/#/persisters/rest) to record some requests to easily test my app in e2e with cypress.

So I have in one of my spec files the following:

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />
import { Polly } from '@pollyjs/core'
import FetchAdapter from '@pollyjs/adapter-fetch'
import RestPersister from '@pollyjs/persister-rest'

Polly.register(FetchAdapter);
Polly.register(RestPersister);

describe('just a test', async () => {
  it('runs a test...', async () => {
    const polly = new Polly("pollyjs-cypress", {
      adapters: ["fetch"],
      persister: "rest",
      persisterOptions: {
          rest: {
              host: 'http://localhost:3000',
            },            
      },
      logging: true,
      recordIfMissing: true,
      recordFailedRequests: true,
    });

    doTest()

    await polly.stop();
  })
})
```

I then start the rest listener:

```sh
$ polly listen
Listening on http://localhost:3000/
```

...but when I run the cypress test I see some requests detected:

```
GET /static/js/47.chunk.js 304 3.621 ms - -
GET /static/js/37.chunk.js 304 4.925 ms - -
POST /graphql 200 42.990 ms - -
```

...but no HAR files are stored at the end.

Has anyone an idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: How are your requests being made? What is happening in `doTest`?